# On the cohomology group of kernel of $\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}(d)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

This is from Mumford-Oda's Algebraic Geometry 2, And here is pdf of chapter 7-8.   [https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~chai/624_08/mumford-oda_chap7-8.pdf](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Echai/624_08/mumford-oda_chap7-8.pdf)
[image]

My question is on page 243, I can't see why $H^{i+1}(\mathcal{K}_1)$ could be computed as shown in the text. I try to use long exact sequence of $$0 \to \mathcal{F}_1 \to \mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{F}/\mathcal{K}_1 \to 0$$, but the only acyclic sheaf is $\mathcal{F}(d)$, which is not in this short exact sequence...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Probably the red framed box is misplaced, it should be under the previous term of (7.1).

Comment: @Sasha Thanks, it seems that you are right

Comment: Hint: the LES says that for $i \geq 1$, $0=H^i(F(d)) \rightarrow H^i(K_2 \rightarrow  H^i(K_2) \rightarrow H^{i+1}(F/K_1) \rightarrow H^{i+1}(F(d))=0$ is exact, hence $H^i(K_2) \cong H^{i+1}(F/K_1)$.